# Survey on image retrieval datasets

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, computer-vision, information-retrieval

I am on a survey about image retrieval datasets. I have found some, such as:

- NUS-WIDE
- Oxford5k
- Oxford105k
- Paris6k
- MSCOCO

I have been way too confused about the detection metrics and the metrics they use inside these datasets for image retrieval purposes. For example:

- AP
- Recall
- Precison
- Mean Average Precision

My question is, how I can identify the metrics that these datasets use for image retrieval purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in [papers with code](https://paperswithcode.com/), in the ["image retrieval" category](https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-retrieval):

[image]

There, you will find multiple datasets and, for each one, the best-performing models according to certain metric, with links to the associated article and source code, e.g.:

[image]